# fixed menu aligned to left

Tags: html, css, menubar

I was working on [this site](http://webzerjob.in/socialmedia/).I have set a fixed menu at the top of the page so that the user can see the menu at any time without scrolling.

I have added the css to menu class as follows to reduce the width.

```
#masthead { 
margin: 0 auto;
width: 86%;
}
```

Now I am getting th efixed menu when scroll down aligned to left.I have tried adding

```
#masthead.fixed-header
{    margin: 0 auto;
width: 86%;
}
```

but this seem no to work.can any one please help to make it center of page.Thank You!!

Comment: When i scroll a bit can't see it :S

Comment: cener tag is deprecated. isnt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

just add `right: 0; left: 0;` to `#masthead.fixed-header` (line 649) in your css

it will look like

```
#masthead.fixed-header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   min-height: 35px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest that you add a `width: 100%;` also. Looks nice then.